# How to rearrange component elements in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have this react page where I used Material UI to design this card. Here is the code:

```
<Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={4}>
   <Card className={classes.cardContainer1} elevation={0}>
     <CardHeader
        title={
           <Typography
              variant="h6"
              component="h2"
              className={classes.cardTitle}
           >
                 {"Atd. Pendentes"}
           </Typography>
        }
        subheader={
           <Typography
              variant="subtitle1"
              component="p"
              className={classes.cardSubtitle}
           >
              {counters.supportPending}
           </Typography>
        }
        avatar={
           <Avatar className={classes.cardAvatar1}>
              {<GroupIcon fontSize="inherit" color="#5578eb" />}
           </Avatar>
        }
    />
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

So I really want to make the avatar towards the end and not at the start and since I am just starting out with Material UI, I have no clue how to rearrange the elements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <CardHeader
    title={
       <Typography
          variant="h6"
          component="h2"
          className={classes.cardTitle}
       >
             {"Atd. Pendentes"}
       </Typography>
    }
    subheader={
       <Typography
          variant="subtitle1"
          component="p"
          className={classes.cardSubtitle}
       >
          {counters.supportPending}
       </Typography>
    }
    avatar={
       <Avatar className={classes.cardAvatar1}>
          {<GroupIcon fontSize="inherit" color="#5578eb" />}
       </Avatar>
    }
    sx={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse' }}
/>
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortnately